# Where is Identity Server login page and how to customize it?

Tags: javascript, angular, asp.net-core, .net-core, identityserver4

I use Identity Server in an Angular project (based on .NET Core) and when clicking Login button on our Angular page it redirects us to a login page that seems to belong to Identity Server on https://localhost:5001/Identity/Account/Login? url. I have look at many pages on Angular and View sides in my project, but there is not a page (razor or html) that seems to be similar to this default login page.

So, my questions are:

**1.** Where is this login page exactly? Is it embedded to our app, or is it hosted in IdentityServer?

**2.** How can I use a custom Angular page instead of this page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its hosted in IdentityServer and you can find the source code for it [here](https://github.com/DuendeSoftware/IdentityServer.Quickstart.UI/tree/main/Quickstart)

or in the **\Quickstart** folder in your IdentityServer project. This is for the official IdentityServer UI.

The thing you might refer to is the UI for ASP.NET Identity, that has its own set of UI components and that one is distributed as part of the ASP.NET Identity NuGet package (as a Razor Class Library .DLL). So that's why you might not see the views and controllers in your project. The source for the package is [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/master/src/Identity) .

See this [blog post](https://andrewlock.net/customising-aspnetcore-identity-without-editing-the-pagemodel/) for details

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using the hosted Identity server UI, in order to view all the views and controllers you have to scaffold the identity files.

If you are using the Visual studio follow the instruction from this link https://www.talkingdotnet.com/how-to-scaffold-identity-ui-in-asp-net-core-2-1/

or scaffold all identity files into an ASP.NET Core MVC project via dotnet?

Follow the below steps in the .csproj location

Step 1: List the files that can be scaffolded

```
$ dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity --listFiles
```

Step 2: Include the files with semi-comma separated

```
$ dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity --files="Account.AccessDenied;Account.ConfirmEmail;Account.ExternalLogin;Account.ForgotPassword;Account.ForgotPasswordConfirmation;Account.Lockout;Account.Login;Account.LoginWith2fa;Account.LoginWithRecoveryCode;Account.Logout;Account.Manage._Layout;Account.Manage._ManageNav;Account.Manage._StatusMessage;Account.Manage.ChangePassword;Account.Manage.DeletePersonalData;Account.Manage.Disable2fa;Account.Manage.DownloadPersonalData;Account.Manage.EnableAuthenticator;Account.Manage.ExternalLogins;Account.Manage.GenerateRecoveryCodes;Account.Manage.Index;Account.Manage.PersonalData;Account.Manage.ResetAuthenticator;Account.Manage.SetPassword;Account.Manage.TwoFactorAuthentication;Account.Register;Account.ResetPassword;Account.ResetPasswordConfirmation"
```

If you omit the --files and --useDefaultUI flags it will generate all the files.

```
$ dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity
```

From this link https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/pull/8752/files